# URLDownloadToFileA(NULL, url, path, 0, NULL); C++

Tags: c++

How would I go about Achieving this code:

```
char *url[100];
char *path[100];
gets(url);
gets(path);
URLDownloadToFileA(NULL, url, path, 0, NULL);
```

The goal is to make a down loader. The user inputs the url he wants to download, and where he wants to save it. When I try to compile I get "cannot convert parameter 2 from 'CHAR [100]' to 'LPWSTR'"??
And is there a clean way to convert char into const char?

Comment: Never use `gets`.  ***Never** use `gets`.  It is impossible to use securely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `*` on the array declarations, and use [`gets_s()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b5x9wc7.aspx) to avoid buffer overflows:

```
char url[100];
char path[100];
gets_s(url, 100);
gets_s(path, 100);
URLDownloadToFileA(NULL, url, path, 0, NULL);
```

Comment: Thank You! Worked like a charm. I would love to give you a vote up but sadly I don't have enough reputation.